# How to log activity on my computer?

Tags: windows-7, logging

I have a simple question, I have a computer at home, and I'm thinking someone from the family is doing things to it while I'm asleep (playing games, downloading stuff).

Now usually, I won't mind, but since it's done at 3am+ it seems suspicious.

Can I have a log of what happened on my own PC? i.e.

```
"Opened application xyz.exe" @ datetime
"Opened website "www.example.com"" @ datetime
```

etc.

---

Is there a program to do it?
I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: @Bob: Added, my bad :P

Comment: " I'm thinking someone from the family is doing things to it while I'm asleep" Password protect all the user accounts, don't give them the passwords, log off all account before bedtime, or shut down the PC.

Comment: Things is, it's is kinda the family's PC. I just want to know what's so damn interesting at 3AM that justifies going inside my room when I'm asleep and using it. (Nothing malicious, just curious)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also try a time monitoring program, like [Manictime](http://www.manictime.com/) (which I personally use in its free edition) or [others](https://web.archive.org/web/20130507132418/https://superuser.com/questions/917/time-tracking-applications).

They will usually log all activity, which programs and websites are used, when, and for how long. Some of them can be hidden also, if you don't want an icon in the systray.

Comment: Ohhh that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

To stop your mother playing games on your PC at 3 a.m. use [Parental Control](http://www.microsoft.com/athome/video/parentalwin.aspx)

> After you've turned on Parental Controls for your <strike>child's</strike> *parent's* standard
> user account, you can adjust any of the following individual settings
> that you want to control:
>
> **Time limits**. You can set time limits to control when <strike>children</strike> *parents* are
> allowed to log on to the computer. Time limits prevent <strike>children</strike> *parents* from
> logging on during the specified hours. You can set different logon
> hours for every day of the week. If they're logged on when their
> allotted time ends, they'll be automatically logged off.

…

> In the Family summary window, click Edit settings for the user account
> or accounts for which you want to customize settings. **You will then be
> able to**:
>
> - Set the desired level of web filtering to determine what
>   types of sites can be accessed.
> - **Review the websites your <strike>child</strike> *mother* has
>   visited, games played, and time spent on the computer.**
> - Manage your
>   <strike>child's</strike> *mother's* contacts in Windows Live Hotmail, Messenger, and Spaces

Comment: +1 for the parental control for controlling the parents XD

Answer (score 1):

Pilixo has a software called Bodi. It allows you to see the detailed analysis of application usage, web browsing, printing, etc. as well as time and length of usage. And it keeps the recording for you, so that you can view and analyze that 3 AM access to your machine. And since Bodi is HTML5 based, you will be able to view the activity from another device. Plus, there is a 30-day free trial so there are no costs associated with it. Give it a try.

Here is the link to Bodi: https://www.pilixo.com/bodi/

Thanks,

Mark G.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on my computer/computer and then from the list you will see
favourites
desktop
recent places
click on recent places it will list on the recent folders and files opened in your pc
to see the date and time of all activities right click anywhere on the blank space on recent places, go to view and select details

Comment: This only gives me directories, it doesn't give me what programs they've opened.